# How can you capture modifier keys exclusively?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

When using NSEvent flagsChanged and ANDing the flags with various KeyMasks, how can you test themin an exclusive way?
Currently, using a series of if else conditions whit the pattern:

```
if ((flags & someKeyMask) && (flags someOtherKeyMask))
```

This will match even if a third modifier key is down. 
Putting longer series of key masks earlier in the if else conditionals makes the behavior work as desired, but feels incomplete somehow. Is the a good way to say "only these modifier keys, not any others"?

Here is a more specific example where the first one matches before the others. I'm wondering if there is a way to add some logic to each one that says "only these modifier keys".

```
if ((flags & (NSCommandKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask))) {
                                               NSLog(@"one");
                                           }else if (((flags & NSCommandKeyMask) && (flags & NSAlternateKeyMask)) && (flags & NSControlKeyMask)) {
                                               NSLog(@"Command+Option+Control ");
                                           } else if ((flags & NSCommandKeyMask) && (flags & NSShiftKeyMask)) {
                                               NSLog(@"Command+Shift ");
                                           } else if ((flags & NSCommandKeyMask) && (flags & NSControlKeyMask)) {
                                               NSLog(@"Command+Control");
                                           } else if ((flags & NSCommandKeyMask) && (flags & NSAlternateKeyMask)) {
                                               NSLog(@"Command+Option ");
                                           }
```

So the correct pattern I was looking for, as provided by Ken Thomases is:
`flags &= (<one or more masks bitwise OR'd together);`
`if (flags == (<one or more masks bitwise OR'd together)) { // do something }`

This gives exclusive matching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to be aware that the value returned from `-modifierFlags` includes some flags which do not exactly correspond to keys. You should construct a mask which includes all of the flags that you care about (whether you care that they are pressed or not pressed). Pass the flags value through that mask and then compare the result with exactly the combination you want.

For example, if you care about Command, Option, Shift, and Control, and you want to know if exactly Command and Shift are down but the others are not, you could use:

```
if ((flags & (NSShiftKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask)) == (NSShiftKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask))
    // do something
```

**Update:** Here's how to check a variety of combinations:

```
flags &= NSShiftKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask;
if (flags == (NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask))
    NSLogs(@"Command+Option+Control");
else if (flags == (NSShiftKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask))
    NSLog(@"Command+Shift ");
else if (flags == (NSControlKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask))
    NSLog(@"Command+Control");
else if (flags == (NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask))
   NSLog(@"Command+Option ");
```

Comment: Yeah, doing that is not the problem. The problem is that if if ((flags & (NSShiftKeyMask|NSControlKeyMask)) comes before that one in the if-else series, it matches even with the same sequence of modifier keys.

Comment: You should only check for the exact combinations you want. If you really have two conditions that are not mutually exclusive, then you have to decide how you want to handle that (do both, do only A, do only B, do neither) and write your code accordingly. Perhaps I'm not understanding something, but this sounds like the old joke: "Doctor, when I move my arm like this, it hurts." "Well, then, don't do that." Put another way: all of your conditions should be of the form I showed and none of the form you wrote.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extended example similar to that in your question (although your question has a redundant case).

Comment: Thanks. So based on this, it is still necessary to test for the broader combinations? Or, does the &= operator produce an exclusive bit field ? I think my fundamental problem is lack of understanding on bit field masks. I was unaware of the &= operator

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by broader combinations. The above is sufficient to test for the key combinations implied by the logging statements. You only need other tests if you want to test for something else.

Comment: Thanks much. &= is what I was looking for. The pattern (flags &= (mask1|mask2)) then testing with if (flags == <one or more bitwise or'd masks>) is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch just the combination pressed, you need to use the switch/break construction:

```
switch (flags) {
            case (NSControlKeyMask|NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask):
                [keystrokes appendString:@"cmd-alt-ctrl-"];
                break;
            case (NSShiftKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask):
                [keystrokes appendString:@"cmd-shift-"];
                break;
            case (NSControlKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask):
                [keystrokes appendString:@"cmd-ctrl-"];
                break;
            case (NSAlternateKeyMask|NSCommandKeyMask):
                [keystrokes appendString:@"cmd-alt-"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```